# mongo is not functional on Git Bash

Tags: mongodb, installation, cmd, git-bash

I just installed Mongo and Mongosh on my Machine, defined the paths for both on system environment variable. I have also used gitbash on my machine for a while.
My problem is when I run some mongo codes on Git Bash they won't operate.
The first one is clearing the screen commands not working.

```
test> console.clear()

test> cls
```

the second one is autocomplete does not operatable and nothing happens when I press tab half-way-through. below I pressed Tab, no outcome!

```
test> show colle
```

The third problem is with Overtype mode. I tried to turn it off but to no use! it still keeps overtyping.

My forth problem when I press Up Arrow to have a copy of last line, it just jumps onto the line above and nothing happens!

And most importantly all above issues do not exist in windows command prompt! only in Git Bash!

Any idea how to fix it up?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problems on my Windows system. Everything works correctly. Either you have out of date software or your software is not installed correctly. Edit your question with details on your operating system and versions of Git Bash and mongosh.

Comment: I uninstalled all pieces of software and reinstalled them from scratch one by one. step by step. issues still persistent. I know too little to say what the problem is but I guess there might be a mongosh library of codes that git bash has no access to. (like settings.json on vs code). ?!